# how can I input decimals in to input field - android

Tags: java, android, decimal

I'm just starting to play around with android app.
I have an text field to input numbers but somehow I can only type in regular integers without decimals.

any idea what I can do so I can input decimals too?

This is what I have..

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
          EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          String input = edit.getText().toString();
          float num = 0;
          try {
             num = Integer.parseInt(input);
          } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
             input = "0";
          }

          double newNum = num * 1.12;
          DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
          text.setText(input + " * 12% = " + df.format(newNum));
```

Comment: use `Double.parseDouble(input)` instead of `Integer.parseInt(input)` ?

Comment: change your `EditText` xml to   `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`

Comment: how do I give you guys a thumbs up? ^_^ thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following attribute to your `EditText` in xml:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

This will inform the keyboard to enter decimals.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to get decimal number keyboard you should add `inputType` with value `numberDecimal` in `EditText` xml file:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

And if you want to use comma and dot also, you should add `digits` also in `EditText` xml:

```
android:digits="0123456789.,"
```

and when you get that result in Java, don't forget to replace dot with comma because Double and Float can only parse dot separated text:

```
String test = "12,34";
String changed = test.replace(",",".")
float value = Float.parseFloat(changed)
```